# Why does only the bride need to move to the groom's place after marriage and not vice versa?

Tags: history, belief, rituals, marriage

Is it written anywhere that only the bride has to sacrifice her parents and move to her husband's place permanently?

Why is it not applicable for the groom to move to bride's family? Only in exceptional and in very rare scenarios will this happen, but not always.

What is the significance behind this sacrifice and why should only girls suffer by a lot of sacrifices? What is the origin of this practice/tradition?

Comment: I understand that you're asking for the case of real people. But just consider the fact that the two greatest deities, Vishnu and Shiva, both moved into their wives' parents homes after marriage  Vishnu married Lakshmi, the daughter of the milk ocean, Kshira-sagara, and he still lives in the Kshira-sagara. Shiva married Parvati, the daughter of the Himalaya, and he still lives on the Kailasa, which is in the Himalaya.

Comment: Gene's and chromosome its Male is the giver of seed so his progeny only continued it's not the other way why would girls parents bring other person progeny because they already have in their home but exceptional case groom can be allowed to stay temporarily and also If the girls parent only have girl child than they can brought up the daughters son as their child son in law can never stay in laws home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why only bride needs to move to groom's place after marriage and not groom to bride's place?

Because in Vedic marriage, the daughter belongs to the groom's family after marriage, and she is no longer part of her birth parents' family. This is also why her gotra changes to her husband's gotra, and also why today her last name is changed to her husband's last name.

Before the daughter is married to a man, she is "given" as a dAna (donation) to a suitable bridegroom:

> Manu 9.88 - One shall give his daughter in the proper form, even though she may not have attained (the age), to a bridegroom who is of exceptionally distinguished appearance, and her equal.

This "giving" means transfer of family membership and thus responsibility of the girl to the groom's family:

> Manu 5.146 - In childhood she should remain under the control of her father, **in youth under that of her husband**, and on the husband’s death under that of her sons; the woman should never have recourse to independence.

From that point on, the wife serves the husband and father and mother in laws, and all the Pitr offerings the couple make go to her new family's ancestors.

That is why this practice is there.